# IoT Big Data design on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis, aws-iot

I'm trying to design a big IoT solution of millions of devices starting from zero. That's why I need a highly scalable platform like AWS.

My devices are going to report data using AWS IoT, and that's the only thing I've really decided. I need to store a lot of data like a temperature measure every 15 minutes on each device so for that measures I've planned to insert those measures directly to DynamoDB using IoT Rules, but on the other side, I need a relational structure to store companies, temperature sensors, etc. So I thought I could store that in MySQL RDS.

After that, I need to configure a proper analysis tool, so I was thinking of Kinesis and load the data from Redshift after ETL using Data Pipeline since AWS Glue doesn't support DynamoDB.

I'm new with some of the services so I don't know exactly what I'm doing and I don't know if this approach is the best one.  What do you think?.

Thanks.

Comment: starting from zero devices, and adding one each year? or do you mean starting from zero code ("starting from scratch")?

Comment: both, I mean, I have an old version which is not using MQTT devices, and I've already coded something similar to AWS Greengrass which is going to take care of local profiles for this new version, for this design I thought I've already configured the IoT side which is receiving all the data from my devices and it's being inserted into Dynamo, but I still need to figure out how to store all the data in the cloud efficiently for future use like analytics.

Comment: tip: avoid aws data pipeline if you can

Comment: @JonScott I've tried avoiding it with AWS Glue but it only supports Relational databases, I need to transform the data from dynamo and RDS somehow before I insert it into Redshift and I don't see any other way... what's the problem with Data Pipeline?

Comment: its very buggy in my experience. there other options such as DMS from dynamo to redshift followed by transformations within redshift

Answer (score 1):

I would have your applications write the edge data (Raw Data) to an S3 bucket with this flow:

Edge(With credentials) -> APIGateway -> Lambda -> S3

Save your Raw data as `.json` files in S3. Then you can use tools like Athena and Quicksight to visualize.

The benefits to this are:

1) Your edge devices don't have to have the AWS SDK

2) S3 is cheep and insanely scalable

3) JSON format can be read by any service so you are not locked into AWS for visualization.